# How to store / load big C++ containers

Tags: c++

I was wondering how can I store C++ containers for efficient loading, for example how can I store very large vectors of integers. I know I can save them in a file, and make new vector out of that data

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    vector<int> data = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; // some elements 
    std::ifstream file(path);
    for (const auto &c : data)
        file << c << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

but if I want to save 1 gigabyte of data, loading it every time from a file takes a loooooooooong time. So is there a way to store this kind of data, for fast loading that doesn't take forever, if possible I would like to store my own classes this way as well.

Comment: Have a look at Boost.Serialization. The last time I used it it was able to load huge chunks of data in seconds.

Comment: Define "loooooooooong". Saving a vector of integers worth 1GB takes 1.63s on my machine with a normal binary `std::ostream::write`.

Comment: Reading `1GB` of data is going to take a while regardless of what you do with it. I suspect that the reading time will greatly overshadow stuffing it into a vector. You could create a separate thread for adding to the vector which may get you something.

Comment: Avoid formatting, i.e. store the raw integers. In any case, it should not take *that* long, even with formatting.

Comment: No matter if you save it as a string inside a file, or as bytes, or inside a database. If it's 1GB and your HDD is slow, then it's gonna be slow to read 1GB from it.
You can try to compress your data (like zip, gz or bz2...)

Comment: @Rakete1111 a more lightweight alternative you could try [cereal](http://uscilab.github.io/cereal/quickstart.html)

Comment: In our software, we dump GBs of data in seconds by just `fwrite()`ing the data as binary. (I've to admit that its much faster to/from SSD than network but this is probably beyond the S/W responsibility.) For reading, we pre-allocate size of a `std::vector` and then just `fread()` the contents to its internal buffer (getting the address with `[0]`). If endianess were(/becomes) a problem I would swap the data after reading.

Comment: @Acorn Unfortunately, "raw integers" is not a format. (If you think it is, tell me how many bytes each integer takes or what the first bytes means.) You still have to convert to some well-defined format otherwise there's no guarantee you'll be able to make sense of the file when you read it back in.

Comment: Use hugepage and keep your data in ram.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: It **is** a format. Each integer is N bytes, N depending on what kind of integers are written. The endianness depends on the platform, but is very well defined. The fact that we do not know the "details" does not mean it is undefined. There is no need for "conversions", at all.

Comment: @Acorn well, endianness depends on how it was written down. Provided that source f data might be not same as platform that reads it. There is reason why for communications  they prefer to use fixed format, e.g. bigendian, least bit first (yeah, bit order also matters). The software is supposed to be able to convert expected format into platform format before processing

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie: Sure, but here the format is fixed. OP can define any format he/she wants, and the format of the integers as used by his/her particular platform is such a fixed format -- and the optimal one, in particular, for performance (which is the topic of the question, by the way).

Comment: @Acorn Where in the C++ standard can I find the guarantee that the endianness will remain the same across multiple runs of the program? How do you know his platform has a fixed format as opposed to one that can vary? (Yes, such platforms have actually existed.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Why would you assume it is *not* guaranteed by *your* (OP's) platform? Why would you assume it can vary? (Yes, I have actually *worked* on configurable-endianness archs -- maybe you just heard about their existence? :-).

Comment: @Acorn I'm not assuming it's not guaranteed by any particular platform. I'm making no assumptions about the platform, which is what you should do when a problem can trivially be solved portably. And you definitely shouldn't suggest a non-portable solution without documenting its non-portability.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I am not making *any* assumptions about the platform. Even if you work on a (non-existent) unicorn platform that randomly changes your endianness between runs *without your control*; you could still detect endianness at runtime and read/write "raw" integers if they match and fixing them or bailing out if they don't. But this is pointless, since no one has ever released such a broken arch.

Answer (score 3):

**std::vector** is stored in a contiguous memory block.
If you want to store/load data from a vector to file you should be able to do something like this.

```
std::string filename{ "test.dat" };
std::vector<int> vec_source = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; // some elements 

// Save to file
std::ofstream OutFile;
OutFile.open(filename, std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::binary);
OutFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(vec_source.data()), vec_source.size() * sizeof(int));
OutFile.close();

// Prepare
std::vector<int> vec_target;
vec_target.resize(vec_source.size());

// Load from file
std::ifstream InFile;
InFile.open(filename, std::ofstream::in| std::ofstream::binary);
InFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(vec_target.data()), vec_target.size() * sizeof(int));
InFile.close();
```

See working example here:
https://wandbox.org/permlink/oQuwXxU8q230FaJC

**[EDIT]**

Few notes and limitations:

**Note 1:** If you plan to do more then just save/load the whole array. Like changing the data and storing only the changes you should consider a better method (like split the data into chunks, save each chunk separately)

**Note 2**: This method is correct only for containers which use contiguous memory block like **std::vector**, **std::array** and **std::string**. It will certainly not work for **std::list** or **std::map**

**Note 3**: Following interesting discussion between @DavidSchwartz and @Acorn in the comments of this post. This code example will work correctly only if the endianness of the platform is constant and same when storing and loading the data from the file. It will certainly will not work in case the platform changes its endianness across runs or if mixing platforms!.

Comment: Will this work on a platform that changes its endianness across runs of the program? Where in the C++ standard do I find the guarantee that won't happen? This is code that might happen to work but is not guaranteed to work, that is, it's awful code, suitable only for a platform-specific one off solution where none of these issues are known to matter. And the code should clearly indicate with comments (or better, platform detection macros that fail at compile time) that it's platform dependent.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Actually, this code would work in virtually *every* arch in existence. If the data needs to be moved to another device with a different endianness (which, to begin with, is an assumption you are making; and a very rare one at that considering the landscape of archs in 2018 and the context of the question), you can trivially write a different routine for a different arch to read the imported files. Finally, the code can be said to be portable and conforming to the C++ standard. What is not portable is the combination of (code, data it generates) pair.

Comment: @Acorn It's not about arches in existence, it's about writing portable code or warning people that their code isn't portable and ideally, ensuring it won't compile on platforms where it's not known to work. We don't want to write code that breaks subtly when a new CPU, new compiler, or new architecture comes out. I don't believe the C++ standard guarantee that one run of such a program can correctly understand anything written by a previous run.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: The point is that this approach should work in every platform. Of course, it generates files with different formats in different platforms, but it does not mean the program cannot be used in a given platform or that you can't port the files if you ever need to move them to a different platform. (...)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: (...) In other words, you seem to imply that "different formats" means "undefined formats", which isn't true. `sizeof(int)` is implementation-defined, and endianness would be as well. Actually, in C++20, endianness might be implementation-defined; see the proposal for `std::endian`, P0463R1.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Finally, there are many other assumptions that the C++ Standard cannot guarantee: the file might not be accessible, the file might be deleted between runs, the data might be corrupted by different means, the data might not be persistently written, the free store or the stack may not be big enough... yet we rely on all those. The fact that we do not warn people about every single caveat in every single question is not a matter of laziness or incompetence; rather, it is a matter of brevity and focusing on the question at hand.

Comment: DavidSchwartz and Acron. Your discussion is very interesting. Thank you for your thoughts. I edited my post with a note about this discussion.